# how install xhprof for php 5.6 on windows

Tags: xhprof

How to install the extension Xhprof on Windows for php-5.6?
I found only this link: http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/xhprof/0.10.6/

Answer (score 4):

**XHProf** was developed by Facebook and **abandoned** when they moved to HHVM. There is now a fork of the project called [Tideways](https://tideways.io/profiler/xhprof-for-php7-php5.6) that promises to add support for PHP versions 5.6 and 7.

Unfortunately Tideways has renamed the functions their library provides so it won't be a simple drop-in replacement. Also, their Windows support seems to be pretty much WIP and their builds are failing a lot. If you feel lucky, you could try downloading the latest successfully built artifact from their [AppVeyor project](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/tideways/php-profiler-extension) but for now it will make sense to do your profiling work on PHP 5.5 or some other platform than Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Last Updated at http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/xhprof

```
10/23/2013 12:29 PM        81960 php_xhprof-0.10.6-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.zip
10/23/2013 12:29 PM        82425 php_xhprof-0.10.6-5.3-ts-vc9-x86.zip
10/23/2013 12:29 PM        82506 php_xhprof-0.10.6-5.4-nts-vc9-x86.zip
10/23/2013 12:29 PM        83488 php_xhprof-0.10.6-5.4-ts-vc9-x86.zip
10/23/2013 12:29 PM        85630 php_xhprof-0.10.6-5.5-nts-vc11-x64.zip
10/23/2013 12:29 PM        85440 php_xhprof-0.10.6-5.5-nts-vc11-x86.zip
10/23/2013 12:29 PM        85741 php_xhprof-0.10.6-5.5-ts-vc11-x64.zip
10/23/2013 12:29 PM        85774 php_xhprof-0.10.6-5.5-ts-vc11-x86.zip
```

So no precompiled dll available
Last commit:
Latest commit 0bbf2a2 on 26 Feb 2015

Answer (score 1):

- Download the pre-compiled XHProf 0.10.6 - PHP 5.6 VC9 NTS binary.
- Paste the downloaded `dll` file to PHP extensions directory.
  *(You can find the directory path in `extension_dir` directive of `php.ini` file.)*
- Append `extension=php_xhprof.dll` directive to the `php.ini`.
- Restart the web server and search`phpinfo()` output for `XHProf`. found? done!
- You might also want to use [`XHGui`](http://github.com/preinheimer/xhprof) fork instead of the built-in UI.

Comment: Here is the problem, becouse in this list isn't present dll for PHP 5.6.

Comment: @user3633165 did you find any answer?

Comment: @skbly7 Your reply doesn't help since there doesn't seem to be a public php_xhprof.dll binary for PHP v5.6. Or, if there is, can you post a link?